# How to ignore kerning of underbrace in math mode

Tags: math-mode, kerning, underbrace

Is there a way to instruct LaTeX to ignore the text in the `\underbrace` for purposes of kerning the equation in math mode?

```latex
\begin{align}
    &x
    \underbrace{(4-3y)}_
    {\text{Positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}
    +4y -1
\end{align}
```

[image]
.

I know that I can use `\mkern-30`:

```latex
\begin{align}
    x
    \mkern-30 % Adding this is a sub-par solution
    \underbrace{(4-3y)}_
    {\text{Positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}
    \mkern-26 % Adding this is a sub-par solution
    +4y -1
\end{align}
```

[image]

but finding the exact number to work out how to fix the kerning is obviously not fun.

Is there a better way?

Comment: use `mathtools` and its `\mathclap{...}` macro: `\underbrace{....}_{\mathclap{...}}`, and next time please post a full minimal example, not just a sniplet, then it is a **lot** easier for others to test your code

Comment: Noted, daleif. Thank's a ton!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subscript can be set in a zero-width box. The size of the subscript should be set explicitly. This results in the same output as `\mathclap` from `mathtools`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &x
   \underbrace{(4-3y)}_
    {\text{Positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}
    +4y -1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    &x
   \underbrace{(4-3y)}_
    {\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize\text{Positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}}
    +4y -1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    &x
   \underbrace{(4-3y)}_
    {\mathclap{\text{Positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}}
    +4y -1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case `\mathclap` is not necessary:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x{\underbrace{(4-3y)}_{\substack{\text{positive}\\[1pt] \forall y \in [0,1]}}} + 4y - 1
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x{\underbrace{(4-3y)}_{\mathclap{\text{positive $\forall y \in [0,1]$}}}} + 4y - 1
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, anyway, the additional pair of braces around the whole

```
{\underbrace{...}_{...}}
```

construction: they're necessary in order to get the right spacing.

Comment: +1 for the "extra set of braces" trick, which converts the `\underbrace` atom effectively into `\mathord`, I suppose.  Or maybe it's deeper than that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes: you can see the wrong spacing in the other answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `[1pt]` in the first solution?

Comment: @Toldry To separate a bit the two lines, they would be too crowded otherwise.